# Executing mv command with Java.exec();

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to move an file via the linux mv command.
I have following code:

```
processBuilder.command("/bin/sh", "-c", "\"mv", "\"" + rawOutput + "/" + dir + "/build/libs/*\"", "\"" + startDir + "/test.jar\"\"");
```

During execution it translates to

> /bin/sh -c "mv "/home/test/update/Test-test-23afi369890Ajk/build/libs/*" "/home/test/test.jar""

While this command executes perfectly via the command line, it fails during execution of the jar.
Following error is given:

```
"/home/test/update/Test-test-23afi369890Ajk/build/libs/*": 1: "/home/test/update/Test-test-23afi369890Ajk/build/libs/*": Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the shell command you want to execute:

```
mv /home/test/update/Test-test-23afi369890Ajk/build/libs/* /home/test/test.jar
```

Here's the Java concatenation that builds this shell command in Java (you should print and copy-paste it to a shell to verify it):

```
String myCmd = "mv " + rawOutput + "/build/libs/* " + dir + "/test.jar";
```

Here's how you can run it in a shell:

```
processBuilder.command("/bin/sh", "-c", myCmd);
```

This gives the following argument list:

1. `/bin/sh`
2. `-c`
3. `mv /home/test/update/Test-test-23afi369890Ajk/build/libs/* /home/test/test.jar`

And for completeness, here's how you *should* have designed it, with a static command string and passing in the arguments as separate parameters to avoid shell injection:

```
String myCmd = "mv \"$1\"/build/libs/* \"$2\"/test.jar";
processBuilder.command("/bin/sh", "-c", myCmd, "_", rawOutput, dir);
```

Whose argument list is:

1. `/bin/sh`
2. `-c`
3. `mv "$1"/build/libs/* "$2"/test.jar`
4. `_`
5. `/home/test/update/Test-test-23afi369890Ajk`
6. `/home/test`

(the `_` becomes `$0`, i.e. the script's filename for use in error messages and similar)

> During execution [my attempt] translates to
>
> ```
> /bin/sh -c "mv "/home/test/update/Test-test-23afi369890Ajk/build/libs/*" "/home/test/test.jar""
> ```

I don't know how you reached this conclusion. The actual argument list it expands to is:

1. `/bin/sh`
2. `-c`
3. `"mv`
4. `"/home/test/update/Test-test-23afi369890Ajk/build/libs/*"`
5. `"/home/test/test.jar""`

This corresponds to the following shell command which probably fails with the same error messages as your Java program (if you're not suppressing stderr):

```
$ /bin/sh -c '"mv' '"/home/test/update/Test-test-23afi369890Ajk/build/libs/*"' '"/home/test/test.jar""'
"/home/test/update/Test-test-23afi369890Ajk/build/libs/*": 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```